# Swift , Share Extension : NSItemProvider loadItem not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a share extension allowing users to add pictures to application ,

everytings working just fine  but NSItemProvider .loadItem not working

this is my code in SLComposeServiceViewController :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    let content = extensionContext!.inputItems[0] as! NSExtensionItem

    for attachment in content.attachments as! [NSItemProvider] {

        let identifier = kUTTypeJPEG as String
        let hasItemConforming =  attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(identifier)

        print("LOG : \(hasItemConforming)") // print True ! so item has conforming

        if hasItemConforming {

            attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: identifier , options: nil, completionHandler: { (coding:NSSecureCoding?, error:Error!) in

                // this func not works and prints nothing

                print("LOG : Loaded") // print nothing
                print("LOG : error : \(error)") // print nothing
                print("LOG : secureCoding : \(coding == nil)") // print nothing

            })
        }

    }

    self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: Is an error thrown?

Comment: @Dopapp no , nothing happens

Comment: @Dopapp What do you mean of  isActive , if you mean hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier , yes it return true

Answer (score 0):

Place

```
self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
```

at the end of completionHandler for attachment.loadItem() instead of viewDidLoad() like so:

```
attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: identifier , options: nil, completionHandler: {
    data, error in
    // Your code here

    self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil) 
})
```